# hapi-swaggered how to group routes and send header in each request

Tags: node.js, swagger, hapi-swagger

I am using this pkg to document my code:

https://github.com/z0mt3c/hapi-swaggered

Is it possible to send header with JWT on each request send from doc?
And how can I group routes together?

Answer (score 0):

To configure your routes using `hapi-swagger` follow these steps:

- Create the endpoint you want, let it be `file1.js`

  ```
  module.exports = function (server, options) {
      server.route({
          method: 'GET',
          path: '/your_path',
          // code goes here.................
      });
  }
  ```
- Create the file to add these endpoints, let it be `index.js`:

  ```
  exports.register = function (server, options, next) {
      require('./libs/file1.js')(server,options);    
    next();
  };
  ```
- Register this `index.js` file in your server in `server.js`:

  ```
  var index = require('index'); 

  server.register([{
      register: require('hapi-swagger'),
      options: {
          apiVersion: "0.0.1"
      }
  }, {
      register: index
  }]);
  ```

  You can maintain all your endpoints in a folder and can register all to `index.js`, providing correct path is enough to register endpoint urls

And to add `JWT` header to the `Hapi-swagger`, you will get details in this [Github](https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger/issues/254) page

And can also use [`hapi-auth-jwt2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-auth-jwt2) `npm` package that supports the authentication scheme/plugin for `Hapi.js` apps using `JSON Web Tokens`

Comment: How will it help to group routes and add header?

Comment: You need not to register all ur routes individually to `swagger`, you can include all the endpoints in `index.js` as mentioned above and register at one shot in swagger. And to add `JWT` header follow the github link provided above.